# Списки в Python. Как обратиться ко всем элементам первого элемента в списке?

Tags: python, list

```
l = [ ]

l.append((x1, y1, x2, y2))  
  
ev3.screen.draw_line(l[0]) # это должно быть аналогично следующей строке
ev3.screen.draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`
```

Comment: "это должно быть аналогично этому" - ничего не понятно. вы уже обращаетесь к `l[0]`, где у вас `x1, y1, x2, y2`

Comment: Используйте распаковку контейнера: `ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[0])`.

Comment: выдает ошибку. Пишет отсутствует аргумент y1. Значит это все он считает как x1

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось.  Количество ответов с плюсами не ограничено, но принять можно только один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый элемент списка - кортеж `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.

Проще всего обращаться: `ev3.screen.draw_line(l[0][0], l[0][1], l[0][2], l[0][4])`

Comment: Запятой не везёт)

Answer (score 2):

Вроде вот так:

```
ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[0])
```

Comment: да, изящнее, чем "в лоб"

Comment: лучше этот ответ примите, он лучше :-)

Comment: ок. За второй вариант тоже Спасибо.